# ScrollViewer in Expander

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, expander

I have a ListBox with Expanders which in turn contains a ListBox.
I would like to have both the ListBox with Expanders (listBox1) and the ListBox inside each Expander (listBox2) to have scroll functionality, but I cannot get the innermost scrolling to work (i.e. scrollViewer1 in my XAML).

How can I get both scrollbars to work?

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer1">
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Expander>
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer2">
                            <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you d'ont need the scrollviewer tags: The listbox handles the scrolling by itself. To control the visibilty of the listbox scrollbar you ca use the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`.

Second, the vertical scrollbar of the inner listbox does not appear because without height limitations the listbox will expand to display all the items.

Here is a working code wich shows both scroll bar of parent and inner listbox :

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Expander>
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Expander.Header>

                    <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" MaxHeight="150">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </Expander>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

To reproduce your problem, just remove the MaxHeight on the second listbox.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make the listBox2 scale it's height to fit the window, when the window resizes?