# How to enable scrolling in Expander without a fixed height

Tags: xaml, uwp, expander, windows-community-toolkit

I'm having problems with scrolling inside the [Expander control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/expander). Since the default behaviour of the Expander is to grow to fit all content, scrolling doesn't work for any child controls as there's no height limit.

Here's a layout I'm trying to make work. I want the Expanders to stretch to the window's height, not over it, and the [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview) inside the first Expander should be scrollable.

[image]

I can get it to work if I set a fixed height on the Expander (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648912/scrollviewer-in-expander)), but as the app window should be resizable, fixed height isn't a solution.

What can I do?

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="my:Expander">
    <Setter Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
  </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<my:MasterDetailsView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Models}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <my:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Model">
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </my:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
  <my:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Model">
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="root" Orientation="Horizontal">

          <my:Expander Header="Expander 1" IsExpanded="True">
            <!-- Should be scrollable! -->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
                      Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
          </my:Expander>

          <my:Expander Header="Expander 2"></my:Expander>
          <my:Expander Header="Expander 3"></my:Expander>
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
  </my:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
</my:MasterDetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close to getting it to work, you just need to change the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` of your `ScrollViewer` to `Disabled`

```
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```